# it is better to create a command that passes as argument paragraphs or better to create an environment?

Tags: macros, environments

My purpose is to create a command that admits two arguments, namely, a title and content (paragraphs), for example,

```
\newcommand{\mytxt}[2]{\clearpage%
\MakeUpercase{\bfseries #1}\newline\newline
#2
\clearpage
}
```

I would like to know if this is the best way to do it or simply I should create an environment.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I'd go for an environment if the contents is typically paragraphs (similar to a `theorem`, say). This seems up to personal preference and likely opinion-based.

Comment: Since `#2` is not manipulated, other than obeying passive declarations that are set up in advance, I would say it is tailor made for an environment.

Comment: An environment with the title as its argument: `\begin{mytext}{title} ....paragraph\end{mytext}`, or make the title optional and use `\begin{mytext}[title] ....paragraph\end{mytext}`. For the latter, `\newenvironment{mytext}[1][]{\MakeUpercase{\bfseries #1}\newline\newline}{\clearpage}`       or     `\newenvironment{mytext}[1][]{\MakeUpercase{\bfseries #1}\newline\newline}{\clearpage}` or, if you don't want a blank link when there is no title, `\newenvironment{mytext}[1][]{\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\MakeUpercase{\bfseries #1}\newline\newline\fi}{\clearpage}`.

Comment: `\newline` doesn't really do what you think it does. Use a paragraph break and maybe a bit of vertical space. Or `\bigbreak` or something similar.

Comment: I want to create an environment that receives an argument and an optional argument in such a way that the first argument will be the title and the optional argument will decide whether the title should be justified to the left or centered. It is posible?